# By definition of $e^{it\partial_x^2}, \partial_x^2 u \in L^2({\mathbb{T}}) $..

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

My proffesor in class said that "By definition of $e^{it\partial_x^2}, \partial_x^2 u \in L^2({\mathbb{T}}) $ if we initially have that $u \in L^2({\mathbb{T}}) $" where $\mathbb{T}$ is the 1-dim torus and $e^{it\partial_x^2}$ is the infinitesimal generator of $i\partial_x^2$. Could someone please help me showing me how come is that true.

Comment: Hmmm. This looks funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
|\left<\partial_{x}^{2}u,\varphi\right>|&=|\left<u,\partial_{x}^{2}\varphi\right>|\\
&\leq\int|u||\partial_{x}^{2}\varphi|dx\\
&\leq\|u\|_{L^{2}}\|\partial_{x}^{2}\varphi\|_{L^{2}}\\
&<\infty
\end{align*}
for all $\varphi\in C^{\infty}({\bf{T}})$, and all such functions are $L^{2}$ dense, so $\partial_{x}^{2}u$ induces a bounded linear functional on $L^{2}$, by Riesz Representation Theorem, there is a corresponding $L^{2}$ function realizing the bounded linear functional, which we again denote by $\partial_{x}^{2}u$.

So the semigroup is defined as
\begin{align*}
t\rightarrow e^{it\partial_{x}^{2}}
\end{align*}
in such a way that 
\begin{align*}
e^{it\partial_{x}^{2}}:u\rightarrow e^{it\partial_{x}^{2}u},
\end{align*}
I think here we need $u$ to be twice differentiable. As a result, 
\begin{align*}
\|e^{it\partial_{x}^{2}u}\|_{L^{2}({\bf{T}})}=1<\infty
\end{align*}
for real-valued $u$ because of that $|e^{it\partial_{x}^{2}u}|=1$.

For real-valued $u\in L^{2}({\bf{T}})$, one can correspond an $L^{2}({\bf{T}})$ function $\partial_{x}^{2}u$ to it, and then we still have $|e^{it\partial_{x}^{2}u}|=1$. Note that this correspondent $\partial_{x}^{2}u$ is real-valued if we are dealing with real Hilbert space $L^{2}({\bf{T}})$.

Comment: And what about the definition of exponential, can be used for something?

Comment: Actually I just learned something about semigroups recently, I need to think about that, still novice.

Comment: I just recall the definition of semigroups or something, you just need to do the similar procedure as above to get the result, no?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't see where u recall the definition of  semigroups, could u please tell me more or less what u have in mind

Comment: I assume the real Hilbert space $L^{2}({\bf{T}})$ for that exponential one.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but thank you man for response, just to clarify something, could u explain me a bit more why $\partial^2_x u$ induces a bounded linear functional, first line